# Periodic reload of data from server in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactivex

I want to create an efficient mechanism for reloading data from server, for my Angular 4 app.

My service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    getData(): Observable<string> {
        // return observable for fetching data from server
    }
}
```

My component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './mytemplate.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
    myString$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private service: MyService) {
        this.myString$ = service.getData();
    }
}
```

My template:

```
<div>
    <p>{{myString$ | aysnc}}</p>
</div>
```

- `myString$` is an observable for a `string` that is loaded from the server.
- `MyComponent` can be loaded as multiple different instances (`myComponent1`, `myComponent2`...).
- As I understood, by doing `myString$ | aysnc`, my component is technically subscribed to `myString$` opn component initializtion, and unsubscribed when component is destroyed.

I want to be able to reload data from the server periodically and emit it to multiple subscribers (components). Since I do not know how much time a request to the server might take, `Observable.interval()` isn't good for me, as if the interval is less time than the time for the request to return, then I'll have a problem of sending a new request before the previous has returned.
I guess I want to block the emission of another request until the previous one "resolved".

What should `getData()` return so that I can achieve that?

Another requirement I have is to not send requests when there are no subscribers, and restart the periodic requests when a new subscriber subscribes - is it possible using `.share()`?

Thanks!

Comment: `.share()` seems like to be the solution to me

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, a solution to your problem would be to wait for the request to finish and then do the new ones? If that's the case you can use concatMap. With concatMap every emission will have to wait for the delayed previous emission to complete before the next one.

Here's an example:

```
let a = Rx.Observable.from(["data1","data2","data3","data4"]);
let b = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click').map(x=>"asyncData");
let c = b.merge(a).concatMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(1000))

c.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

Here you have a stream of data being emitted every second, and every time you click you get new data. This new data will be added at the end of the stream every second.

So you would get something like this:

- second1 --> "data1"
- second2 --> "data2"
- (mouse click event)
- second3 --> "data3"
- second4 --> "data4"
- second5 --> "asyncData"

Did that help?

Comment: Thanks for replying!
Forgive me for not understanding - how exactly with your solution I would make a new request happen only 7 seconds after the previous one completed?

Comment: With this solution the new request will have to wait for the old ones to finish first. 
If you set the delay method to 1000 (as in the example above), and you do 3 requests, each one will happen every second. If before those 3 seconds end you make a new request, the new request will happen at second 4.
So in your case you would have to set delay() to 7000, to guarantee that every request will spaced out 7 seconds.